# Image service with GeoServer, PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers

I haven't setup or deployed any web services and most help seems to be around vector data... I need input on how to set up and optimize an image service with GeoServer, PostGIS to use in OpenLayers client.

Images are in 32 bit float, GeoTIFF, time-series images (Sentinel-2, Landsat-8) for disconnected areas (think like Hawaii, Montana, Ontario, Alberta), i.e. same area will have different dates of imagery over time and some areas might have images of the same date.
Want to serve old and newer imagery as they become available and so some automation will be nice. Want the user to be able to see the images and be able to view/query pixel values (e.g. NDVI).

Do I setup a folder to which images are downloaded to and this folder sync images to the raster folder in GeoServer and updates the image service? Can this be fully- or semi-automated?

Comment: If you want to serve to OpenLayers (in a web client) then note that TIFF is no good, because it's not supported natively by browsers.  If you want to have users query the data then you'll need to configure a WCS, but note there's no built-in support for WCS in OpenLayers

Comment: @nmtoken Ok thanks. If you were to design and set this up, how would you do it? Images are downloaded as 32-bit float reflectance GeoTIFF images.

Answer (score 1):

[Geoserver's REST API](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/index.html) may be useful for automating your processes.

For steps like downloading image data, uploading data to the database and accessing the Geoserver REST API you could use Python or maybe a shell script.

Comment: Are there other platforms that have similar REST protocols for data management?